# mount.cifs stopped working

Tags: samba, mount

Recently my mount of a samba share stopped working. Windows clients aren't having trouble, but no luck from Ubuntu 14.04. fstab says:

//fox/ktenney/Documents /home/ktenney/Documents cifs credentials=/root/.creds,rw,uid=1000    lm  0   0

/root/.creds says:

```
user=ktenney
password=mypass
```

When I run $sudo mount -va

I get errors

Credentials formatted incorrectly: (null)

mount error(5) Input/output error

I'm quite certain the samba server, fstab and .creds file haven't changed since the mount was working fine.

Suggestions?

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score -1):

I have the equivalent of 
/root/.creds:

```
username=WORKGROUP/ktenney
password=mypass
```

cifs can be tested with:

```
 mount -t cifs -vvv -o credentials=/root/.creds //fox/ktenney/Documents /home/ktenney/Documents
```